# How to get an HTML element by his content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, meteor

I need to modify the HTML of an element at the loading of the page so it's not on a event.

The things I can do is to get all informations that this element contains (like name, state etc...) with this:

```
Meteor.call("whereAreYou",function(err,succ){
    if(err){
      console.error(err);
    }else{
      console.log(succ);
      if(succ == undefined){
        Session.set("isNotHome", false)
      }else{
        var theMachine = InfosMachines.find { ipAddr: succ };
        //change the HTML
        Session.set("isNotHome",true);
      }
    }
  });
```

and the structure of the element is:

```
<li class="liMachine switch">
        <div id="nameMachine">
            <h3>{{nameMachine}}</h3>
        </div>
        <div id="stateMachine">
            State:<span class="state">{{stateMachine}}</span>
        </div>
        {{#if is_running_machine}}<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>{{else}}<button type="button" class="stop {{#if to_hide_stopM}}hidden{{/if}}"></button>{{/if}}
        {{#if is_alive_machine}}<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>{{else}}<button type="button" class="kill {{#if to_hide_stopM}}hidden{{/if}}"></button>{{/if}}
        {{#if is_stopped_machine}}<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>{{else}}<button type="button" class="start {{#if to_hide_startM}}hidden{{/if}}"></button>{{/if}}
    </li>
```

I want to do something like

> element where nameMachine is "XX" do ....

But I don't know how to make the request.

Someone could put me on the right track ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're happy with a case insensitive match on any part of the string you can use `:contains`:

```
$('#nameMachine h3:contains("XX")');
```

Alternatively, if you require a full match of the string with case sensitivity you can use `filter()`:

```
$('#nameMachine h3').filter(function() {
  return $(this).text().trim() == 'XX';
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your nice answer but I think there is a typo error in your first answer right ?

Comment: Ah yes, I got your `id` wrong, it's `nameMachine` not `machineName` :)

Comment: I haven't noticed that ^^ I was pointing this `$('#nameMachine h3:contains("XX");` and I think it should be `$('#nameMachine h3:contains("XX")');`

Comment: Oh yeah, that too!